# Extract residuals from heteroskedasticity robust standard model (lm_robust())

Tags: r, linear-regression, robust

I need to extract residuals from a model in R where I have used

```
lm_robust(XS1 ~ rmrf + smb + hml + umd, data=df)
```

Does anybody know how to do it, please?

The use of `residuals()`, `resid()`, `rstandard()` don't work with this function.

Answer (score 2):

```
library(estimatr)
model <- lm_robust(XS1 ~ rmrf + smb + hml + umd, data = df)
df$residuals <- (model$fitted.values - df$XS1)
```

Can you calculate the residuals like this?

Comment: Yes, thank you!! I’ve always forget about the simple way of doing things.